# How to pass the logged in user to direct_to_template?

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm using `direct_to_template` for a url but I need the logged in user to display the page. How do I pass it to `direct_to_template`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable in `settings.py` is set to include `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'`, it will already be on the page context. (This is configured by default).

The `direct_to_template` generic view uses `RequestContext`, so there will be a context variable called `user` that will provide the currently logged in user (or an `AnonymousUser` if there is no logged in user).

For example, to display the username in your template: `{{ user.username }}`.

For more details see the [django docs on the auth context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth).

Answer (score 0):

put following in your login view before GET method

```
def custom_proc(request):

        return {
            'app': 'myapp',
            'user': request.user,
            'ip_address': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        }
```

in login view in post

......some code here......

```
return render(request, 'html file name',
              context_instance=RequestContext(request,processors=custom_proc]))
```

in setting.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (                         'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

and in html file

```
Hello, username = {{ user.username }} id ={{ user.id }}
```